# github API oauth with laravel/socialite: doesn't return email

Tags: php, laravel, github, oauth-2.0, laravel-5

I'm trying to use Laravel Socialite extension.

The URL it generates for github has `scope=user%3Aemail`:

```
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=111111&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8880%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fgithub&scope=user%3Aemail&state=222222&response_type=code
```

Then is requests https://api.github.com/user?access_token=$token
And the response seems to be OK except for the email field: it's `null`. Other fields looks good: `login`, `id`, `avatar_url`, etc...

How can I get user email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a pull request to this problem:

https://github.com/laravel/socialite/pull/41

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Socialite documentation on Github, it has a pretty simple method to redirect and get the whole user object. I am sure there will be an email in there.

https://github.com/laravel/socialite

Comment: As I mentioned before, default scope contains `user:email`. It seems to be a bug, and I made a pull request.

Comment: @DmitryR it doesn't return a name too.

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on the privacy settings of your GitHub account